# Scala convert model object to DTO

Tags: scala, playframework, functional-programming, implicit-conversion

I'm scala newbie and trying to understand it's base concepts. With use of play/scala/slick I'm trying to implement trivial app which allows user to perform CRUD operations on another users. So problem I faces is that I don't understand how I should use implicit conversions to convert model object to DTO object.
Here is what I've got so far:

`Application.scala` (Controller class):

```
//returns list of users  
def users = Action.async {
    val userList = userDAO.all()
    userList
      .map { list => Ok(list.map(elem => Json.toJson(elem))) }
      .recover { case _ => InternalServerError }
}
```

`User.scala` (model object, represents entry in database):

```
case class User(id: Long, login: String, password: String) extends BaseEntity
```

`UserDto.scala` (DTO, object, representing User in user list):

```
case class UserDto(id: Long, login: String) {
  implicit def userWriter = Json.writes[UserDto]

  implicit def user2UserDto(user: User): UserDto = UserDto(user.id, user.login)
}
```

In code above, at #1 tag, I get a error which states that `User` can't be converted to json. Exact error message: **Error:(40, 53) No Json serializer found for type Application.this.userDAO.Entity. Try to implement an implicit Writes or Format for this type.
      .map { list => Ok(list.map(elem => Json.toJson(elem))) }**. How and where should I implement conversion from User to UserDto so that it works and not, say, ugly?

For example, in Java I would implement each Dto object with `public User to()` and `public static UserDto from(User user)` so that I can convert them. Should I do the same in scala or there is more elegant way to accomplish this task?

**EDITION**
Edited version of `users` method:

```
def users = Action.async {
  val userList = userDAO.all()
  userList
    .map { list => Ok(list.map(elem => Json.toJson(elem : UserDto))) }
    .recover { case _ => InternalServerError }
}
```

Have the following compiler errors:

```
Error:(41, 24) not enough arguments for method apply: (implicit writeable: play.api.http.Writeable[Seq[play.api.libs.json.JsValue]])play.api.mvc.Result in class Status.
Unspecified value parameter writeable.
      .map { list => Ok(list.map(elem => Json.toJson(elem : UserDto))) }  


Error:(41, 24) Cannot write an instance of Seq[play.api.libs.json.JsValue] to HTTP response. Try to define a Writeable[Seq[play.api.libs.json.JsValue]]
      .map { list => Ok(list.map(elem => Json.toJson(elem : UserDto))) }
```

It seems that compiler doesn't see `userWriter` in `UserDto` object.

Comment: `userList
      .map { list => 
          Ok(userList.map(list => 
              list.map(elem => Json.toJson(elem)))) }` Why do you map over `userList` but not use any of the items therein, but instead map over it again for every item? Also `list.map(elem => Json.toJson(elem))` can be written as `list.map(Json.toJson)`. Please provide the exact error message you're getting, when calling `toJson`.

Comment: @sirius, I added a error message I get on compilation. Please, see updated answer.

Answer (score 2):

Don't define the implicits *inside* the case class. Define them in a [companion object](http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/tour/singleton-objects.html):

```
case class UserDto(id: Long, login: String)

object UserDto {
  implicit def userWriter = Json.writes[UserDto]

  implicit def user2UserDto(user: User): UserDto = UserDto(user.id, user.login)
}
```

When you define them inside a case class, they become instance methods only available from an instance of the class. When you define them on a companion object, they are defined globally (not tied to an instance) and they are equivalent to static methods in java. From there, scala's implicit resolution mechanism [can find them](http://daily-scala.blogspot.com/2010/04/companion-object-implicits.html).

Comment: Thank you, Alvaro! I fixed this bug, but unfortunately compilation error didn't go away.

Comment: To get the implicit to work, it needs this path: `User -> UserDTO -> Writes[UserDTO]`. But implicits don't chain like that automatically. You need to be convert the `User` to `UserDTO` explicitly, or help the compiler a bit by providing a type ascription: `Json.toJson(elem : UserDTO)`

Comment: Thanks a lot, Alvaro. I was able to resolve this issue, but then compiler started complaining about `writes`... I update code and here is the error:  `Error:(41, 24) Cannot write an instance of Seq[play.api.libs.json.JsValue] to HTTP response. Try to define a Writeable[Seq[play.api.libs.json.JsValue]]
      .map { list => Ok(list.map(elem => Json.toJson(elem : UserDto))) }`. Migration to scala is really tough..